# Converting HTML string into DOM elements not working with React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting HTML string from an API, now I want to convert it into DOM elements, this is working in normal html but not working in React JS.

My code:

```
var xmlString = "<div id='foo'><a href='#'>Link</a><span></span></div>";
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
console.log(doc.firstChild.innerHTML); // => <a href="#">Link...
console.log(doc.firstChild.firstChild.innerHTML); // => Link
```

React App giving error:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object DocumentType]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

### Update

@Rai Hassan I'm getting below error:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Can you please provide the Reactjs Code in which you are trying to parse, maybe I can help.

If you are trying to render html in Reactjs you can use this code:

```
<div
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: '<p>test</p>'
  }}></div>
```

Replace the `<p>test</p>` with the html string you have got from api.